# focus+context graph in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

I am using focus + context graph to display historical data. But it is highly inaccurate. I have data every 10 mins for last week. I want the viz to be blank for when data is unavailable. As you can see in the screen shot attached, I have no data between Thu 25 to Fri 26 12pm. But still it shows as if there was data. Can I have color only where data is present?

Is this possible with focus + context, or should I pursue another form of visualization?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function drawChart(user_name) { 
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
        margin2 = {top: 430, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        height2 = 500 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%a %e %H %M").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
        y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
        xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
        .x(x2)
        .on("brush", brushed);

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.receiveddate); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.gtse); });

    var area2 = d3.svg.area()
        .interpolate("monotone")
        .x(function(d) { return x2(d.receiveddate); })
        .y0(height2)
        .y1(function(d) { return y2(d.gtse); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

    d3.json("rest.php/lastweek"+"/"+user_name, function(error, data) {
          var allData = data.records;
          var gtsef = [];
          allData.forEach(function(d) {
            var formattedDate = new Date(+d.receiveddate).toString();
            d.receiveddate = parseDate(d3.time.format("%a %e %H %M")(new Date(formattedDate)));
            d.gtse = +d.gtse;

            gtsef.push(d.gtse);
          });

          x.domain(d3.extent(allData.map(function(d) { return d.receiveddate; })));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(allData.map(function(d) { return d.gtse; }))]);
          x2.domain(x.domain());
          y2.domain(y.domain());

          focus.append("path")
              .datum(data.records)
              .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
              .attr("d", area);

          focus.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis);

          focus.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis);

          context.append("path")
              .datum(data.records)
              .attr("d", area2);

          context.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
              .call(xAxis2);

          context.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x brush")
              .call(brush)
            .selectAll("rect")
              .attr("y", -6)
              .attr("height", height2 + 7);
    });

    function brushed() {
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.select("path").attr("d", area);
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The area is generated for the part where you have no data due interpolation.

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
```

This interpolates the area curve between nearest data points, in this case the data either side of Thu 25 to Fri 26 12pm.  As you have data for every ten minutes, if you generate data for the time period 25 to Fri 26 12pm to be zero then you should get the expected curve.

It might also be worth reading the [area.interpolate docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-area_interpolate) for a summary of the different interpolation methods.